# What is streaming video?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, streaming, udp

I do this in my code, capturing a frame from camera, opening a UDP connection, and sending frame data:

```
    UDP_Client.Connect(Host, Port)
    Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Data
    UDP_Client.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length)
```

I do it every 400 ms.
Is it streaming video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming is basically playing a video from a network source, you can stream live video or pre-recorded video ala YouTube.

Your source at 400ms is 2.5fps, but technically speaking even 0.0001fps is still a video feed just very slow.  What is the definition of a video, a sequence of still images, so as long as the picture does update it can be considered a video.

Is 2.5fps a good video feed, maybe not but it is still video.